# Where eclipse stores Environment Variables

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

Where does Eclipse store Environment Variables for java program?
Does it store in our project directory? or Eclipse configurations?

Comment: If you are asking about the Run Configuration the variables are stored in the launch configuration.

Comment: probably too late answer but I found them in project directory at ".settings/org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs". Not for java but c++.

Comment: I fonud that for a spring boot application my env passed to the launch configured with the boot dasboard end up in a file under  .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\*.launch

Answer (score 0):

Environment Variables are attached to a "Run Configuration"(Run -> Run Configurations). Then you create a new Java Application run config, and will see Environment tab on the right panel.

Comment: This is not what OP asked.